# How does preprocessor resolve the path of linux kernel' head file?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I am new to C programming language, and currently trying to add new `syscall` to Linux kernel by re-compiling the kernel.

When I read the source code, I found it very difficult to locate the path of head file.

For example:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* for printk */
#include <linux/syscalls.h> /* for SYSCALL_DEFINE1 macro */

SYSCALL_DEFINE1(printmsg, int, i)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Hello! This is a msg %d", i);
    return 1;
}
```

This is one of my customized system calls. I edited the MakeFile in `kernel/` folder and `syscall_64.tbl` . After re-compiling, it worked. No compiling error.

However, my problem now is how the preprocessor resolves the path like `<linux/syscalls.h>`. Based on my previous understanding, the preprocessor would go to the folder `/usr/include` for searching. Certainly, there is ***no*** `linux/syscalls.h` within `/usr/include`.

I found `linux/syscalls.h` is actually in linux's project `include/linux/` .

I was wondering what makes the preprocessor search within the project just like `include " "` when it is actually using `<>`.

I was wondering if it is because of some part of MakeFile? If so, which command in MakeFile could make this happen?

Thank you for any help, and please let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: How do you build the kernel after you modify it? Do you use KBUILD? https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/kbuild.html

Comment: The gcc compiler is passed `-I` argument by Makefile to add include directories.  Examine the gcc command which is run.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I simply ran ```make menuconfig``` and ``` make```

Comment: print more verbose informstion and seatch for `-I....`

Comment: `/usr/include` is *one* place a UNIX C compiler conventionally looks for headers.  It is not the *only* place such a compiler may look.

Comment: The kernel Makefile has -nostdinc to exclude /usr/include

Comment: If a kernel build is looking in `/usr/include` I'd be a bit worried. The kernel should be a self-contained project, not reliant on the system it is built on.

Comment: If you build the kernel with `make V=1` the make output will show the full command lines used to invoke the compiler and other programs instead of showing abbreviated output such as `CC      init/main.o`. You can examine those commands lines. They are very long!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pre-processor have a number of built-in search paths (`gpp -print-search-dirs`), and others can be added at run-time via the `-Idir` option.